# How to go through mysql table in multithreading avoiding dublicates

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, innodb

I am working with a multithreaded application that has to select an unique row from mysql using where statement.

`order by RAND()` worked until the table got larger and now it's taking over 1s for each request, that is why I am trying to implement the `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` functionality, so that each thread would get **the first not locked row** from the database.

I am testing the commands in mysql workbench, but I am failing to understand the whole concept, because it just doesn't work. The command being exected:

- `SELECT * FROM main.items LIMIT  1 for update SKIP LOCKED;`

returns one row as expected, but if the command is ran again - the same row is returned, shouldn't it be locked until it's get updated? Or should the update be made in the same request?

Basically there is a database of 100k unique rows, and the script has to go through each of the rows and update them in multithread, using order by rand() is too slow,

Maybe that's not the correct approach, if so please let me know what are the other available options - thank you.

**P.s** Mysql version is 8.0.24 , and table engine is InnoDB

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the processing takes more than a few seconds, do not use the database's locking mechanism.  Instead, have an extra column that says what 'worker' has 'checked out' the row.  When it finishes, it can clear that column.

Decide how many workers to have.  Suggest twice the number of CPU cores on your server.

Divide up the ids into that many chunks and assign each worker a range of ids to work through.  How to do the chunking depends on what unique id exists for the table, whether it is numeric, whether there are gaps, and many other things.  So provide details like that, if you need further help.

Alternatively, keep another table that tracks the id (again a unique key is needed).  Then have a transaction that finds the next id after the last taken id and updates this extra table.

"Don't queue it, just do it." -- In some cases, a queuing mechanism is more costly than simply processing the items.  Please provide some info on how long it takes to process one row.

I see "multithread", but no clues of how you intend to do that.  C++ works one way, Perl another way, PHP depends on the web server, HTTP works another way, Workbench has no multithreading unless you are somehow typing into multiple instances of that tool.